# storing value to doubly linked list in C

Tags: c

I have a doubly linked list data structure which is well formulated, as I have tested it on different inputs.

But, here is a piece of code where I have problem. I am trying to read in a line of string from a file, and store the values by converting them into integers in an array of integer called num. The code is fine unto here as I have printed the entries out and checked them. But when I try storing them into my doubly linked list, I get all the values correct except the second value which is an arbitrary long integer. I have my code and output below:

num_read is a function which reads all the values in a doubly linked list, and takes the array num and its length as arguments.

```
#include "DlistInterface.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

Dnode *num_read(int *,int *);

int main(){
    Dnode *number;
    int num[100];
    char a[10];
    char *lineptr = NULL;
    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int index = 0;
    size_t len;
    ssize_t read;

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("Dlist_v_array.txt","r");

    while ((read = getdelim(&lineptr,&len,32,fp)) != -1){
            i = 0;
            index = 0;
            while (1){
                    if ((lineptr[i] == ' ') || (lineptr[i] == '\n')) break;
                    else a[index++] = lineptr[i++];
            }
            a[index] = '\0';
            num[j] = atoi(a);
            printf("%d ",num[j]);
            j++;

    }
    //printf("\n %d",j);
    printf("\n");
    fclose(fp);
    free(lineptr);

    number = num_read(num, &j);

    while (number != NULL){
            printf("%d ",number->data);
            number = number->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

Dnode *num_read(int *n, int *len){
    int k;

    for (k=1; k< *len;k++){
            //printf("%d ",n[k]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    Dnode *number = (Dnode *)malloc(sizeof(Dnode *));
    number->data = n[0];
    number->next = NULL;
    number->prev = NULL;
    Dnode *another_node;
    Dnode *temp;
    another_node = number;
    k = 1;
    while(k < *len){
            temp = (Dnode *)malloc(sizeof(Dnode));
            temp->data = n[k++];
            temp->next = NULL;
            another_node->next = temp;
            temp->prev = another_node;
            another_node = temp;
    }
    return number;
}
```

I get this as the output:
12 21 33 4 5 6 7 8 9

12 -2109715456 33 4 5 6 7 8 9

The first line of output is because the verification of values read in the number array, which is correct according to the values in the .txt file.

But the same values on the next line have their corresponding second entries to be a weird number, which happens to be their always, no matter what I do.

I desperately need help on this one. I will be very thankful to you all for the help. Please help!!!

Comment: note that return type of `getdelim` is `ssize_t`.

Comment: `Dnode *number = (Dnode *)malloc(sizeof(Dnode *));` --> `Dnode *number = (Dnode *)malloc(sizeof(Dnode));`

Comment: Yes! I got that mistake, but that's not the problem here unfortunately. The values are getting read properly in lineptr and stored appropriately in num array as is evident from the printf to num array. This prints exactly the required line as the first line of output. See the first printf("%d ",num[j]); this is doing its job here. During later value storage in the linked list, there is something fishy, which I have been having trouble finding.

Comment: note `sizeof(Dnode*)` < `sizeof(Dnode)`

Comment: Thanks a lot that solved the problem.....thank you very much for your time and concern related to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect amount of memory assigned [@BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34378993/storing-value-to-doubly-linked-list-in-c#comment56499650_34378993).

```
// Dnode *number = (Dnode *)malloc(sizeof(Dnode *));
Dnode *number =    (Dnode *)malloc(sizeof(Dnode));
```

---

To avoid this mistake in the future, and to create simpler original and maintainable code, use;

```
// pointer = malloc(sizeof *pointer * number_elements)
Dnode *number = malloc(sizeof *number);  // number_elements == 1 in OP's case

// check pointer
if (number == NULL) return NULL;  // detect and handle out-of-memory somehow
```

This has advantages

1. In C, the cast on `malloc()` is not needed.
2. by using the `sizeof *pointer` rather than `sizeof(element_type)`, less chance to get the wrong type, as OP did in this post, and less to update should the type change.
3. By using the `sizeof()` first, the memory needs are calculated in at least `size_t` math.  This becomes important with large programs:  Consider `int h,w; malloc(sizeof *pointer*h*w)` vs. `malloc(h*w*sizeof *pointer)` where `h*w` overflowed `int` math, but not `size_t` math.
4. Always check for `out-of-memory`.  At a minimum, it saves time in debugging as at least you know, proper memory allocated. Note: on some systems, if `number_elements` is 0 (and so is `sizeof *pointer * number_elements`) allocating 0 bytes may return `NULL` and that is *not* an out of memory condition.

   ```
   pointer = malloc(sizeof *pointer * number_elements)
   if (pointer == NULL && number_elements > 0) Handle_OOM();
   ```